# implementing while loop in rock, paper, scissors

Tags: python

I'm very new to coding so don't mind the baby code. i managed to set up a simple RPS game, however, for my assignment i need to use an infinite loop to make the program ask for the input again if the user makes an error. for example, if the enter 'roc' or 'scisor'. I cannot figure out where to input the while loop to make it ask for the input again. here is what I have so far:

```
player=input('rock. paper. or scissors?:')
computer_options= ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
computer=random.choice(computer_options)

if player==computer:
    print('draw')
elif player=='rock':
if computer=='scissors':
    print('you win')
else:
    print('you lose')
elif player=='paper':
if computer=='scissors':
    print('you lose')
else:
    print('you win')


while player != computer:
print('you picked the wrong option')
break
```

Comment: You should keep your implementation completely inside the while loop in order to get the user input and computer generated random output again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `while` on the outside, and put your `break` in an `if` block inside the loop:

```
while True:
    player=input('rock. paper. or scissors?:')
    computer_options= ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    computer=random.choice(computer_options)

    if player==computer:
        print('draw')
    elif player=='rock':
        if computer=='scissors':
            print('you win')
        else:
            print('you lose')
    elif player=='paper':
        if computer=='scissors':
            print('you lose')
        else:
            print('you win')


    if player != computer:
        print('you picked the wrong option')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
computer_options= ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
computer=random.choice(computer_options)

while True:
    player=input('rock. paper. or scissors?:')
    if player.lower() == "rock" or player.lower() == "paper" or player.lower() == "scissors":
        if player==computer:
            print('draw')
        elif player=='rock':
            if computer=='scissors':
                print('you win')
            else:
                print('you lose')
        elif player=='paper':
            if computer=='scissors':
                print('you lose')
            else:
                print('you win')
    else:
        print("you did a mistake, select again between rock, paper or scissors")
        continue
```

I created an infinite while loop. You need to insert the variable `player` inside this loop to play the game, then I inserted the condition `if player.lower() == "rock" or player.lower() == "paper" or player.lower() == "scissors":` meaning that if you wrote correctly the word, the game is starting, otherwise you will receive the message "you did a mistake, select again between rock, paper or scissors". Then, the word `continue` starts the loop again and you will have to put a new value to the variable `player`.

Tell me if you need any more help, for exemple adding the possibility to leave the game or anything else

Comment: awesome it worked thank you!! thats great for now

Comment: Perfect! Then if it worked could you please upvote and accept my answer please? Thank you so much!